Azure Openai gpt-4o-2024-08-06 model is giving response as Could not parse response content as the length limit was reached
I am using gpt-4o-2024-08-06 model with structured output. In documentation it is mentioned that this model support Context window 128k and Max output tokens supported are 16384. I have given the code which i have followed in my project. The error i am getting is as follow.
Could not parse response content as the length limit was reached - CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=5000, prompt_tokens=21633, total_tokens=26633, completion_tokens_details=None, prompt_tokens_details=None)
How to resolve this error.
The code which I have followed is given below.
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI()

class CalendarEvent(BaseModel):
    name: str
    date: str
    participants: list[str]

completion = client.beta.chat.completions.parse(
    model="gpt-4o-2024-08-06",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "Extract the event information."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Alice and Bob are going to a science fair on Friday."},
    ],
    response_format=CalendarEvent,
    max_tokens=5000
)

event = completion.choices[0].message.parsed


Why do you expect that there's a different answer than "you're exceeding the limit"? Do you think it should work with the data you're sending? Also, shouldn't you be using max_completion_tokens? max_tokens seems to have been deprecated.

The parameter you are looking for in the Playground is called Maximum length and in the API max_tokens.

@Luaan the model which i am using has 128k context window. the input i am passing is in that limit and max tokens also under the limit. but still getting the error. i want to know why i am getting this error.

@Sanjeevani refer to this  link  for OpenAI models to large documents

max_tokens is deprecated see https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat-create-max_completion_tokens

max_tokens is the token generated  from completion, that is including output tokens and reasoning tokens.
You can check this documentation.
So, you need to give the max_tokens greater than the completion token else you will get error.
See below example.
Completion token is 17 which is difference of total and prompt tokens.

Now, if i give max_tokens as 17 i get below error.
LengthFinishReasonError: Could not parse response content as the length limit was reached - CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=17, prompt_tokens=92, total_tokens=109, completion_tokens_details=None, prompt_tokens_details=None)


When i give greater than 17 it is working fine.

So, you give the max_tokens greater than the difference of total tokens and prompt tokens, in your case it is greater than 5000.
